# how to theme form in edit/add mode - optionwidgets / content taxonomy widget/other weights drupal

Tags: php, drupal, widget, cck, taxonomy

till now i figured out how to theme the view of the form but im unable to modify the form values / options of CCK in edit/add its just ignores me and sometimes i cant even see the options array when i do form alter.... anyone can help and give some method how to theme edit/add cck built in weights / content taxonomy weight?

Answer (score 1):

I invite you to use the #theme attribute in a hook_form_alter() call. More info on > http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#theme

With that you can override how the form is rendered.